# SetId on category results on exception

Tags: magento2, catalog, object-manager, repository

I would like to set my **ID** on the **category** `Category::setId` but this results in the following exception: "**No such entity with id = x**".

My code:

```
$catFactory = $objectManager->get(CategoryFactory::class);
$catRepo = $objectManager->get(CategoryRepositoryInterface::class);
$cat = $catFactory->create();
$cat->setId(100);
...
$catRepo->save($cat);
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can not set category id by yourself while creating category programatically. It will be generated by magento it-self because it is primary key and associated at many place in database. So category id create thing will manage by magento code code.

So remove line from your code:

```
$cat->setId(100);
```

You can use below code for create category programatically:

```
use \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;

include('../app/bootstrap.php');
$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
$url = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$storeManager = $url->get('\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');
$mediaurl= $storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA);
$state = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');
/// Get Website ID
$websiteId = $storeManager->getWebsite()->getWebsiteId();
echo 'websiteId: '.$websiteId." ";

/// Get Store ID
$store = $storeManager->getStore();
$storeId = $store->getStoreId();
echo 'storeId: '.$storeId." ";

/// Get Root Category ID
$rootNodeId = $store->getRootCategoryId();
echo 'rootNodeId: '.$rootNodeId." ";
/// Get Root Category
$rootCat = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category');
$cat_info = $rootCat->load($rootNodeId);

$categorys=array('Levis','Wranglers','Basics'); // Category Names
foreach($categorys as $cat)
{

$name=ucfirst($cat);
$url=strtolower($cat);
$cleanurl = trim(preg_replace('/ +/', '', preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9 ]/', '', urldecode(html_entity_decode(strip_tags($url))))));
$categoryFactory=$objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory');
/// Add a new sub category under root category
$categoryTmp = $categoryFactory->create();
$categoryTmp->setName($name);
$categoryTmp->setIsActive(true);
$categoryTmp->setUrlKey($cleanurl);
$categoryTmp->setData('description', 'description');
$categoryTmp->setParentId($rootCat->getId());
$mediaAttribute = array ('image', 'small_image', 'thumbnail');
$categoryTmp->setImage('/m2.png', $mediaAttribute, true, false);// Path pub/meida/catalog/category/m2.png
$categoryTmp->setStoreId($storeId);
$categoryTmp->setPath($rootCat->getPath());
$categoryTmp->save();
}
```

Reference : https://vinothkumaarr.wordpress.com/2016/05/13/add-multiple-category-programmatically-magento2/